# How to skip several lines of an Excel file in php?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have an Excel file (xlsx) with several pictures

And I have this php script that allows me to extract the photos contained in it, insert them in a folder and rename them according to the name of the cells in front of each photo.
The script works but I would like to start reading the lines from line 5. I tried with `$i <= 3` to skip the first 4 lines but this causes a shift in the picture names. How can I solve my problem?

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$path = 'C:/wamp64/www/Extract_pictures_Excel/imagetest.xlsx';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

$i = 0;

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing ) {
    $i++;
  

    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );
        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        switch ($drawing->getMimeType()) {
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_PNG :
                    $extension = 'png'; break;
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_GIF:
                    $extension = 'gif'; break;
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_JPEG :
                    $extension = 'jpg'; break;   
     }
    } 

    else {
        $zipReader = fopen($drawing->getPath(),'r');
        $imageContents = '';
        while (!feof($zipReader)) {
            $imageContents .= fread($zipReader,1024);
        }
        fclose($zipReader);
        $extension = $drawing->getExtension();
        $chemin = 'C:/wamp64/www/Extract_pictures_Excel/images/';
     
    }

    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    foreach ($sheet->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    $row = (int)substr($drawing->getCoordinates(), 1);

  // retrieve the image data anyway you like

    $stylecode = $sheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
    $colorcode = $sheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue();
    $finalname = $stylecode.'_'.$colorcode;
    $myFileName = $chemin.$finalname.'.'.$extension;
    file_put_contents($myFileName,$imageContents);
 
  }
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `getDrawingCollection()` gives you a list of all the drawings on the active sheet, but this list is not directly related to cell coordinates. So skipping some items of this list is **not the same** as skipping rows.

Not sure how this goes with the old PHPExcel libs, but with current PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet, a [Drawing or BaseDrawing](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Worksheet-BaseDrawing.html) objects should have their [$coordinates](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Worksheet-BaseDrawing.html#property_coordinates) property.

Example:

```php
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
foreach ($sheet->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
  $row = (int)substr($drawing->getCoordinates(), 1);

  // retrieve the image data anyway you like

  $stylecode = $sheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
  $colorcode = $sheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue();
  $finalname = $stylecode.'_'.$colorcode;

  ...
}
```

You should parse the `$drawing->coordinates` in order to retrieve values of it's neighbouring cells.

Comment: So the best is that in my function "call_user_func" I add "$drawing->coordinates" to have the coordinates of each image ?

Comment: @Patrick62, not in `call_user_func`, just withing the `getDrawingCollection()` result loop. See my edited answer.

Comment: Your code is good, just change $drawing->coordinates to $drawing->getCoordinates() and it works well